# Which is a lighter object

Tags: c#, object

I am confused here. Which is lighter object? is orgWithNullImageCollection or orgWithImageCollection ? in the below code. Or is it lighter object concept at all. Please find the code snippet below for the reference.

```
class Orgnization
{
    public Collection ImageCollection { get; set; }
}

Organization orgWithNullImageCollection = new Organization();
org.ImageCollection = null;


Collection imageCollection = new Collection();
// Adding 100 images to imageCollection

Organization orgWithImageCollection = new Organization();
org.ImageCollection = imageCollection;
```

Is there any difference in performance if I pass these two objects to any other methods? ie passing orgWithNullImageCollection over orgWithImageCollection ?

I believe that, it won't make any difference whether ImageCollection property of Organization objects points to something or not.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never pass *objects* in C# - only ever values of value types, or references. In this case, you'd be passing a reference as you're dealing with a class. The reference will be the same size (4 or 8 bytes) regardless of the contents of the object it refers to (if any).

In this case, both objects will be the same size - it's just that one of them will have a null reference where the other has a reference to a collection.

As such you could regard the one with the collection as "heavier" in that are two objects involved instead of one. The extra collection will take memory, obviously - whereas a null reference doesn't refer to any object, so only the size of the null reference itself is required.

For more information, see my article about [value types and reference types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) and [argument passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).